# Does Amazon DynamoDB Encryption Client work with Amplify DataStore?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, flutter-aws-amplify

I have a Flutter app with AWS Amplify's DataStore as backend. Is client side/in transit encryption possible for the DynamoDB DataStore is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encryption client is built using both Java or Python. You handle the encrypting of the items before you sent them to the datastore, so while it is possible, most likely not when using flutter.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dynamodb-encryption-client/latest/devguide/what-is-ddb-encrypt.html